# Grab $_session variable from PHP file and use in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

I'm fairly new when it comes to using scripting languages so I'm struggling to get my head round the concepts.

Basically I have this form

```
<form method="post" action="/list/process.php">
 <input type="email" name="address" value ="Email" />
 <input type="hidden" name="lists[]" value="122" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Join" />
</form>
```

process.php validates the email address for the correct syntax and if successful checks the address against a database to see if it already exists ("unsubscribe") or not ("subscribe")

I included this snippet of PHP to the page of the form

```
<div id="result">
<?php
   if ($_SESSION['result'] == ("fail"))
    {
    echo "<p>Please enter a valid email address!</p>";
    }

   if ($_SESSION['result'] == ("success") && $_SESSION['action'] == ("subscribe"))
    {
    echo "<p>Thankyou for joining, you will shortly receive an email at $_SESSION[address]' with a link to your free download.</p><p>Note: if you do not receive an email, please check your junk folder and mark the message as safe.</p>";
    }

   if ($_SESSION['result'] == ("success") && $_SESSION['action'] == ("unsubscribe"))
    {
    echo "<p>You will shortly receive an email with a link to unsubscribe from the mailing list.</p>";
    }
?>
</div>
```

Not sure if my PHP syntax is up to scratch (I'm new to it) but it works. Of course div#result shows up as "Please enter a valid email address!" when you initially load up the page because $_SESSION['result'] comes back with "fail". All of the other possibilities work when I submit the form.

Now how would I go about replicating this PHP snippet in AJAX? I imagine that it would involve posting the form to process.php using AJAX, getting the three session variables back, and then processing them in the above manner (but in JavaScript) to display one of the three messages in an initially hidden div (#result) in a popup/bubble manner.

The question is how? I have no experience in using AJAX and it seems like the only way I can achieve the desired outcome.

Thankyou for your help.

Adam

Comment: Good jumping off point for getting into ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You don't need AJAX to make it work.  If the user loads the page for the first time the $_POST array should be empty, $_SESSION['result'] shouldn't be set to fail if $_POST is empty, only if $_POST['email'] is set, but invalid.

Comment: AHA you're right! When I tried it yesterday the browser must have had a leftover session in the cache! I added <?php session_start();?> at the top of the page with the form on it and I assumed that no data coming through in the first instance would cause $_SESSION['result'] to fail, not the case at all it seems!! I'm still new to this but learning quite a lot from my trail and error, thanks guys, and cheers again @DigitalPrecision for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of sessions is probably unnecessary in this instance.

Here's what I would do:

- When the form first loads, hide `div#result` with javascript.
- When someone submits the form through `process.php`, process the form and return a JSON array containing a list of error messages and a variable denoting whether submission was successful.
- The AJAX side should recieve the response, look at the success variable and if it is false, insert those messages into `div#result` and unhide the div.

Comment: OK, so is a JSON array another format for the PHP session variables? The problem is I am using a mailing list program called Simple Mailing List 2 which is still in beta and is written entirely in PHP (except for some back-end UI). So the form processing goes through a number of PHP pages for processing, database submission, etc and I'm not savvy enough with PHP yet to make any drastic changes.

Comment: JSON is just an open exchange format that is easily to read and parse. It can be thought of as being able to do the same job as XML. Javascript and PHP should be able to process it natively. In your case you would not have those session variable checks in the `page of the form`. Instead, move them to process.php and then return a JSON result.

Comment: So the three session variable checks that I have on the page of the form can be processed in process.php and then returned as a JSON result. That seems a whole lot more streamlined than what I have been trying to do! So would I encode the individual variables like so: json_encode($_SESSION['result']); json_encode($_SESSION['action']); and json_encode($_SESSION['address']); first, or would i do the checks first and then turn them into their own JSON arrays?

Comment: You should do the checks first, and if everything is fine, then encode all of those into a JSON response: `json_encode(array('result' => $_SESSION['result'], 'action' => $_SESSION['action'], 'address' => $_SESSION['address']));` you can then return the encoded result.